# C void pointers in API Design ideas

Tags: c

I am working on a large project that is provided to our customers as a static c lib and one header file that has the prototypes for our exposed API. The project has two similar but unique builds that require different data structures to be exposed in the header. I am trying to come up with the best design to allow a single API function to work with different data structures depending on the build.  This is my idea so far, but I'm worried this is a bad design.

My function will be implemented like this

```
void foo(void *generic_data_struct)
{
#ifdef BUILD1
   build1_t *data_struct = generic_data_struct;
#else
   build2_t *data_struct = generic_data_struct;
#endif
...
}
```

And the exposed API header will be, depending on the build the customer orders, either

```
void foo(build1_t *data_struct);
```

or

```
void foo(build2_t *data_struct);
```

Is this a reasonable design pattern or is this frowned upon?   Thanks!

Comment: The two structs I use are very similar and only differ in one element. Thus, the vast majority of the processing is the same and that's why I'd like to have one function handle both (as well as reducing variations in our API). The one element that differs will be handled using additional #ifdef directives.

Comment: you could check out how other libraries handle this.. [Core Foundation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/) on OS X comes to mind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not like this:

```
#ifdef BUILD1
foo(build1_t *data_struct)
#else
foo(build2_t *data_struct)
#endif
{
  /* ... */
}
```

AFAIK, the standard does not require different pointer types to be bitwise compatible, so your original idea might not be portable to all possible implementations. It would've been if the prototype also used `void*` (but that of course sacrifices some type safety in the process).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I just wanted to write.

Comment: IMHO, that's horrific.  It's ugly and unreadable.  There is no grace.

Comment: @BlankXavier, I don't agree. It's not very nice perhaps, but surely readable; Zack's solution is perhaps more easily maintainable (and thus preferable), though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the solution I'm going with for now.

Comment: @eq-: apart from anything, what happens when there is a build3?  and a build4?

Comment: @BlankXavier, considering that the distributed API is defined in terms of the build, you can well just extend the compile-time branching.

Comment: @eq-: but that is my point; you'd end up with a long list of #ifdef with prototypes between, and that is not sustainable.  It does not scale.  Imagine functions where to read them, you have to mentally parse the prototype!  it would be like reading a foreign language using a dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

It is almost always better to use an opaque type (`struct foo;`) for this kind of thing, rather than `void` pointers.

Whenever you have variant builds, minimizing the number of #ifdefs is highly desirable.  I recommend you use eq-'s proposal, but factor out variations in function prototypes with a typedef:

```
/* header file */
#ifdef BUILD1
typedef build1_t generic_t;
#else
typedef build2_t generic_t;
#endif

void foo(generic_t *);
void bar(generic_t *);
/* etc */
```

You still need #ifdefs *inside* `foo`, `bar`, etc whenever actual behavior changes based on `BUILD1`, but you don't need them on the declaration and definition of every single function.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct generic_struct {
    union {
        struct specific_struct_1 struct_1;
        struct specific_struct_2 struct_2;
    };
};
```

This gives you a single type that holds both structure definitions in overlapping space.

Comment: I have considered this but the problem is that then this will have to be included in the header we send the customer. This will require some of our older customers to change their code when we give them an update, and will also give them visibility into the other data structures that aren't used by their build.   I'm not writing this idea off, just not sure yet.

Comment: I personally think this is a bad idea, because it means the compiler will not detect when non-BUILD1 fields are used in BUILD1 code or vice versa.  Also, if `struct_1` and `struct_2` are not the same size, `generic_struct` will be the size of the largest member of the union.  In an embedded, every-cycle-counts context, that's very much not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you not to use compile-time directives to separate functionality.  Select at run-time; use if() statements and have some state indicating mode.

Comment: I would prefer to do it this way, but I'm working on real-time embedded algorithms where every cycle counts. I also don't want to require our customer to specify the mode when they call our APIs because their library is only going to be capable of using one mode or the other. I need to make the API as simple as possible for them including not giving them extra information or requireing extra information from them.  I could just use separate functions for the separate functionality but there would be a lot of redundancy introduced into the codebase.

Comment: By mode, I mean to say somewhere in a header file, you do have an #ifdef, and you use it to set the mode, which you check at run-time.  I have to say, I find it improbable that the overhead of an if(), which is likely to *literally* amount to *a* cycle, is so onerous that code maintainability is better sacrificed.